# Moment returning an invalid date while using Hermes JS Engine

Tags: react-native, momentjs, moment-timezone, react-native-hermes

When I was using `jsc` Engine, everything was working fine but when I shifted from `jsc` engine to `Hermes` Engine in my react native app I started getting Invalid date where I was using moment.

**CODE:**

```
const defaultDate = moment(currentTimeStamp).format("YYYY/MM/DD"); //till this it works fine
return moment(defaultDate).toDate().getTime(); // throws INVALID DATE
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some R&D, I was able to figure out the issue myself so I thought to share it here.

**Solution 1 :**

Instead of using format like **`format("YYYY/MM/DD");`**. Use it like **`format("YYYY-MM-DD");`** as this is one of the standard format that moment understands.

**Solution 2:**

If you need that format only(which was my case). You need to tell the moment the format that you are using. Like this:

```
return moment(defaultDate,"YYYY/MM/DD").toDate().getTime();
```

Comment: What about if you need millisecond times? How can I format this >>> "1975-08-19T23:15:30.000Z"

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when working on a project that was relying moment to parse the format. To get to moment to work with Hermes I had to explicit express the format as so `moment(defaultDate,"YYYY/MM/DD")`. So came with a more dynamic solution:

```
import moment from 'moment-timezone'; // or ''
const parseFormat = require('moment-parseformat');

/**
* @description This function will parse the date time string and return a moment object. This was created to fix a bug with Hermes JS engine.
* Explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71421582/moment-returning-an-invalid-date-while-using-hermes-js-engine and here: https://github.com/facebook/hermes/issues/865
* @param {string} dateTime - date time string
* @return {moment} - moment object
*/
export const momentWithFormatParser = (dateTime: string) => {
  if (typeof dateTime === 'string') {
    const test = moment(dateTime, parseFormat(dateTime));
    return test
  }
  return moment(dateTime);
}
```